# Not able to install tensorflow in Mac M1

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, apple-m1

I am trying to install tensorflow on my Mac M1 and I am getting the following error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

I have python3- 3.9.7, pip- 21.3.1

Comment: Hi! Could you check out these threads for installation of Tensorflow in Mac M1   https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/            https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/51506#issuecomment-901460541

Answer (score 2):

Below is the simplest and efficient way from which we can install tensorflow in Mac M1

NOTE: Mac M1 has ARM64 arch not X86_64 so we need to be very careful while downloading packages. Anaconda is available for Mac M1 users : https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2022.05-MacOSX-arm64.sh

Following are the steps to victory:

Download Anaconda from above link
create virtual env ( Optional )
pip install tensorflow-macos
Thats it!

Reference video link which may be useful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DgWvU0p2bk

Comment: What is Anaconda?

Comment: It is bundle which consists of all the packages generally required by the Data Scientists
you can read more about it here: https://medium.com/pankajmathur/what-is-anaconda-and-why-should-i-bother-about-it-4744915bf3e6

Answer (score -1):

I was encountering the same problem, it's really a really simple solution. You must:

1. Go to https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge and download the corresponding file for your system.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyBCc.png)

2. Go to terminal and type `bash /Path/to/file.sh`
3. Run

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately when I run that file, it gives an error:
`+ mamba install --yes --channel conda-forge --override-channels jinja2 curl libarchive 'constructor>=3.4.5'
scripts/build.sh: line 14: mamba: command not found`